# Count of bit different in each cell between two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of binary strings as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['111','101','011'],'B':['01','10','00']})

A      B
111    01
101    10
011    00
```

and the reference dataframe of binary strings as follows:

```
ref = pd.DataFrame({'A':['111','111','111'],'B':['00','00','00']})

A      B
111    00
111    00
111    00
```

I would like to count the number of bit different for each cell pair-wise between df and ref.  The expected output is the following.

```
A      B
0      1
1      1
1      0
```

So far, I can count the difference of two bit strings using the following idea.

```
count = sum(1 if a != b else 0 for a,b in zip(str1,str2))
```

However, I could not apply such idea using apply() with pandas dataframe because str1 is in the df and str2 is in ref.  May I have your suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why the last cell in column `A` of expected output is 2? Should be 1?

Comment: Oops.. Sorry my typos.  it should be 1.  Thanks.  I have edit already

Comment: Wait you need to need to difference between the cells in binary ?

Comment: You should fix the `pd.DataFrame({'A':['111','101','001'],'B':['01','10','00']})` to `pd.DataFrame({'A':['111','101','011'],'B':['01','10','00']})`

Comment: I have edited it. Thank you very much Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['111','101','001'],'B':['01','10','00']})
ref = pd.DataFrame({'A':['111','111','111'],'B':['00','00','00']})

diff = lambda s1,s2: sum(1 if a != b else 0 for a,b in zip(s1,s2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for column in df.columns:
    df2[column] = list(map(diff,df[column],ref[column]))
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  0  1
1  1  1
2  2  0
```

Comment: Is that applicable with python 3?  I tried that and get the df2 as follows.

A                                   B
0  <map object at 0x000000000722BB70>  <map object at 0x00000000071EAE10>
1  <map object at 0x000000000722BB70>  <map object at 0x00000000071EAE10>
2  <map object at 0x000000000722BB70>  <map object at 0x00000000071EAE10>

Comment: @RatchainantThammasudjarit Try `df2[column] = list(map(diff,df[column],ref[column]))`

Comment: Wow! perfect.  Thank you Alex.

Comment: @RatchainantThammasudjarit No problem! Be sure to accept my answer!